# Language specific redirects with UrlRewrite sitecore module

Tags: multilingual, redirect, urls, url-rewrite

I've done alot of looking around but I can't seem to find the answer to an issue I am facing.

Is it possible to use the UrlRewrite module from the Sitecore marketplace to perform language specific redirects?

For example, let's say I have a multilingual site called *example1.com* and I want *example1.com/**en**/initial-url* to redirect to *example1.com/**en**/redirected-url*,
but I only want this to happen for the 'en' language.

I wouldn't want *example1.com/**fr**/initial-url* to redirect anywhere.

In the Match section of the inbound rule I created, these were the values of each field:

Match Type - Matches the Pattern 
Using - Regular Expressions
Pattern - `en\-gb\/questions.*`

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I've managed to get this working by amending the `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage`
setting to `true`. As recommended by jrap, test thoroughly if you change this setting.

Comment: Have you tried including the language in the match URL? I would think it should just work.

Comment: I've attempted this but it doesn't appear to work. I had an inbound rule with the language included in the path I specified in the pattern field

Comment: Can you include what you had in that field in your question for more context?

Comment: Sure, in the Match section of the inbound rule, these were the values of each field: Match Type - Matches the Pattern, Using - Regular Expressions, Pattern - en\-gb\/questions.*

Comment: I would recommend adding it into your question so it's easier to read and more readily available to others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Dan, I have now added it to the question.

Comment: Watch out for the setting `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage`. If `true`, it will strip the language from the request prior to the request becoming visible in the redirect module. But, don't simply change this without significant testing.

Comment: Thanks, jrap, I think that is the setting I've been after. I have existing redirects so will have to test to see if it has any impact